# What are the best IxD/UI Pattern libraries?

Tags: design-patterns, resources

Quite a few question as about design patterns for x or y interface. Where are the best design pattern libraries?

Comment: I've collated and reviewed the contributions to date in a blog post: http://bit.ly/8y6knU

Comment: @JonW we redirect some questions here as being duplicate. I think this is a question that should be reopened and made community wiki (my 2 cents)

Answer (score 18):

Here are some useful pattern library resources that I know of:

- [12 Standard Screen Patterns](http://designingwebinterfaces.com/designing-web-interfaces-12-screen-patterns)
- [40+ Helpful Resources On User
  Interface Design Patterns](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/15/40-helpful-resources-on-user-interface-design-patterns/)
- [Designing Interfaces: Patterns for
  Effective Interaction Design](http://designinginterfaces.com/)
- [Pattern Tap](http://patterntap.com/)
- [patternBrowser](http://www.patternbrowser.org)
- [the Diemen Repository of Interaction
  Design Patterns](http://www.visiblearea.com/cgi-bin/twiki/view/Patterns/Home_?skin=print)
- [The Interaction Design Patterns
  Page](http://www.visi.com/~snowfall/InteractionPatterns.html)
- [UI Patterns - User Interface Design
  Pattern Library](http://ui-patterns.com/)
- [iOS UI patterns](http://pttrns.com/)
- [Use Your Interface](http://useyourinterface.com/)

Answer (score 7):

Adding a few more resources I've come across to the many already great suggestions above:

1) Pattern libraries:

- UI Pattern Factory: http://uipatternfactory.com/
- Nokia Mobile Design Patterns: http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php

2) Other related resources, blog posts, anti-patterns:

- Patterns to avoid for iPhone developers (antipatterns): http://vator.tv/news/show/2009-04-02-patterns-to-avoid-for-iphone-developers
- iPhone Application UI Design Patterns (blog post): http://flyosity.com/application-design/iphone-application-design-patterns.php
- Designing Social Interfaces: 5 steps, 5 principles, 5 anti-patterns (slideshare presentation): http://www.slideshare.net/emalone/designing-social-interfaces-5-steps-5-principles-5-antipatterns-2014474
- Typographic Design Patterns and Best Practices: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/20/typographic-design-survey-best-practices-from-the-best-blogs/

Answer (score 3):

Resources i've used in the past are:

- [Welie.com](http://www.welie.com/patterns/) - Interaction design patterns
- [Yahoo! Design patterns](http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/)

Matt

Answer (score 3):

To add a few:

- [ecommr](http://www.ecommr.com/): ecommerce examples
- [Designing social interfaces](http://www.designingsocialinterfaces.com/patterns.wiki/index.php?title=Main%5FPage)

Answer (score 3):

The UX Pattern Explorer by Infragistics Quince is great:
http://quince.infragistics.com/

Answer (score 2):

I have recently started my blog of safety-related HCI patterns for touch-based applications at [patterns.intuio.at](http://patterns.intuio.at/), a rather specialised collection of patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Echoing earlier posts: 
+1 to [Yahoo! Design Patterns](http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/) and 
+1 to [UI Patterns](http://ui-patterns.com/)

Both are very useful, in comparison to [Quince](http://quince.infragistics.com/#/Search). The Yahoo! pattern library sets a nice standard that I enjoy referring back to as a resource. The Quince interface is a bit over the top to be something I would want to use regularly.

Answer (score 1):

Patterns Libraries Collection http://profs.info.uaic.ro/~evalica/patterns/