# Do you know any comparative resources like mobile-patterns.com

Tags: design-patterns, mobile, resources

[Mari Sheibley](http://www.marisheibley.com/) is the lead designer of foursquare and has created this awesome site [comparing mobile UI patterns](http://mobile-patterns.com/) - for example showing how a *feed* page looks in different applications, etc.

I've found this site very useful and was wondering if you know of similar resources, either covering other patterns and platforms (web apps, desktop stuff, other mobile platforms).

(just to clarify - I don't know Mari and am not affiliated with her in any way)

Comment: For general pattern libraries, not just mobile, take a look at the older questions http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/4622/4200 and http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/6030/4200

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This is a recent blog post of mine from here: http://uxformobile.com/mobile-pattern-galleries -- I'll replicate it here:]

I've stumbled upon several different mobile UI pattern libraries over the past few weeks and thought I'd compile a list of them to share:

http://androidpatterns.com - Android-centric, but also an excellent example of what (at least in my opinion)is a quality pattern library should consist of: wireframes, examples, clear description and specific dos and don'ts.

http://pttrns.com - screenshot gallery of iPhone applications .

http://mobile-patterns.com - similar to pttrns.com but with more vowels

http://lovelyui.com - another gallery of screen shots.

I'm still on the fence as to whether I like Dribbble or am annoyed by it (maybe I'm annoyed because no one has invited me yet), but it can also be a source of mobile inpsiration as well when browsing via some of its tags:

http://dribbble.com/tags/ios

http://dribbble.com/tags/interface

http://dribbble.com/tags/iphone

http://dribbble.com/tags/mobile

Answer (score 5):

I'd say [UI Patterns](http://ui-patterns.com/), [Lovely UI](http://www.lovelyui.com/) (pretty iPhone-heavy, unfortunately) and [Android Patterns](http://www.androidpatterns.com/) are something I use pretty often and find very useful.

Answer (score 4):

For mobile you can go to http://pttrns.com/ .. but it's really iPhone-Heavy

Answer (score 1):

The biggest collection of inspired mobile UI patterns in the world - http://inspired-ui.com.

Disclaimer: I created inspired-ui

Comment: Please mention your association with links you post.

Answer (score 0):

I've compiled a library of [Mobile Design Pattern galleries](http://mobilegui.net/inspiration/) (24 so far).

Answer (score 0):

I have bookmark some iPhone/mobile sites, there may be some repeating sites, but hope this will help

[Mobile Web Design: Best Practices](http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/mobile-web-design-best-practices/)

[Top 6 Help Design Patterns for iPhone Apps | inspireUX – User Experience quotes and articles to inspire and connect the UX community](http://www.inspireux.com/2011/02/07/top-6-help-design-patterns-for-iphone-apps)

[Recent / iOS UI Patterns (beta)](http://pttrns.com/)

[iPhone 3G/4G tester - online website test emulator with flip](http://iphonetester.com/)

[Breadcrumbs | Patternry](http://patternry.com/p=breadcrumbs/)

Answer (score 0):

Similar site like [pttrns.com](http://pttrns.com/) is 
[androidpttrns.com](http://androidpttrns.com/).

This gives patterns for Android smartphones unlike Iphone patterns in pttrns.com.

Answer (score 0):

I like Patterns of Design - though the site features only iPad and iPhone UI currently. There are many iPhone/Android phone specific pattern sites and not enough iPad/Tablet UI/UX resources - IMO.

http://www.patternsofdesign.co.uk/