# Could you point out to touch-screen interface patterns (inclusive of iOS/android/blackberry)?

Tags: design-patterns, touch-screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do you know any comparative resources like mobile-patterns.com](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/7801/do-you-know-any-comparative-resources-like-mobile-patterns-com)

I have seen a few patterns page, but can you point out to interesting screenshots or patterns for touchscreen, such as it helps me to create a library of touchscreen patterns/screenshots, something similar to **www.patternsofdesign.co.uk**

Comment: HI @inkmarble this is a pretty much a duplicate post, so to prevent answers being added to two different questions I've closed this one off and linked to the other post. Hopefully you'll find some useful examples on that question.

Answer (score 1):

I like http://inspired-ui.com/. All mobile UI patterns.